# How to fetch column based on the column names stored in other table using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have list of column names of each template. If a template has been selected I have to fetch only specific columns mapped for that template. Column names for template have been stored in a separate table.

How to form a query / logic for this? To get values for the specific template using a SQL Server stored procedure.

Comment: You will either have to use a dynamic query (OR) consider doing it in your application logic.

Comment: Yes i have achieved it by dynamic query.

Answer (score 0):

```
 declare @query1 nvarchar(max)
 set @query1 =(Select AccessColumns from TemplateAccess where     
 TemplateName=@TemplateName) 
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(AccessColumns) 
                from TemplateAccess
                group by AccessColumns
                order by AccessColumns
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

 set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
ReportDetail rd inner join [dbo].[Report_DatesDetail] rdd on  
rd.CRIMS_ParentId =rdd.CRIMS_ParentId and rd.CRIMS_ChildId =     rdd.CRIMS_ChildId  
inner join Mas_Application on [Application] = ApplicationName'

exec sp_executesql @query
```